# How do I change the number on x-axis (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx() 

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4lwI.png)

I wonder if I could change the value on the x-axis. Thank you!!!
(The system forces me to type more words instead of code...)

Comment: What do you mean by 'changing the value on the x-axis'? What do you want it to be?

Comment: If you want to change the values i.e. of the blue sinus plot (going from -1..+1) you need to multiply or add something to the numbers in data2. I.e. `data2 = 2 * np.sin(2*np.pi*t) + 2` will give you a sinus going from 0..4.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, Actually I want to change the numbers on the x-axis. For example, changing the [0,2,4,6,8,..] to [2000,2001,2002,2003,...]

Comment: Try `axes.set_xticks`

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_xticklabels()` with proper list of values.

```
ax2.set_xticklabels([1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005])
```